# Displaying thai characters in web page on iOS

Tags: iphone, html, macos, character-encoding, internationalization

I've got 2 asp.Net web applications which are translated into Thai.

When viewed on an iOS device, some characters (we believe those with both upper and lower diacritics) don't appear (squares).

*UPDATE* - The characters are non-unicode - 63242, 63243 etc.

*UPDATE 2*

- Same happens on OSX so an apple issue.
- characters are http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f70b/index.htm and f70a. (should be 0e49 and 0e48?)

The characters display fine on windows, android etc. Also the iOS devices can view other Thai pages fine (thai wikipedia for example)

I've tried a variety of things to rectify but with no luck;

- specifying lang="th" in html tag
- changing font-family to Thonburi and sans-serif (these work for th.wikipedia + others)
- meta charset="UTF-8" in the head
- *update* charset="TIS-620"

Am I missing something? How does iOS choose fonts and encoding differently to other platforms?

Comment: can you tell your URL i.e. i could test this ?

Comment: If the characters aren't unicode then you really should change them (if it is in your control) to unicode.

Comment: @sosborn can you eleborate? Do you mean change the content to something else? Those codes do not have a unicode pointer, but how come windows/android browsers display them correctly and iOS does not?

Comment: I mean change the character encoding to only UTF-8. There is no reason to not use UTF-8 and if you do that you will not run into any problems.

Comment: @sosborn do you mean a) set the charset of the page to UTF-8 or b) trawl through the content changing individual characters to a valid unicode value? a) doesn't work and b) would take an age + I don't have any problems on non-apple devices!

Comment: Without seeing your URL it is impossible to know exactly what is going on. Can you create a sample document that recreates the issue?

Comment: Also, if you are creating the HTML in .Net you should be able to set the encoding to UTF-8 universally (most frameworks offer a way to do this) without going through everything manually.

Comment: @sosborn http://192.168.1.55/ Should show an A with Thai diacritics. It does on windows, android etc. but not on iOS, OSX.

Comment: Tried to look at it but I can't connect to the server. That is a local IP address, not accessible from outside of your router.

Comment: @sosborn sorry, brain-freeze. see [here](http://dmills.webuda.com)

Comment: I've looked at that page on a couple of computers (OS X and Windows 7), and numerous browsers (IE9, Chrome for mac and windows, Safari for mac and Windows, Firefox for Windows) and none of them showed the proper character.

Comment: Thanks for your help @sosborn. Interesting that you can't see those characters on windows, I can. Also chrome/stock internet app for android shows them fine. I have resigned myself to having to change the content to valid unicode, it's just frustrating that some browsers interpret them correctly and others not.

Comment: That is why you should always use Unicode. As for why you can see it and I cannot, it sounds like maybe you have fonts installed that I do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characters in question are not valid Unicode and therefore there is no consistency in which browsers/OS will render these as intended.

The only reliable solution is going to be to convert the invalid characters to valid ones.